# asp.net cookies being shared between instances on same browser (formsauthentication)

Tags: asp.net, session, cookies, browser, forms-authentication

Hi so this probably has a very simple answer..

So my question is I'm using formsauthentication with webmatrix in asp.net razor pages.. what my application does is let one user have multiple "subscriptions" and when the user logs in they get to select what "subscription" they want to log in as now the problem is I want the user to be able to have two windows open and have different "subscriptions" on each window.
If I'm storing the current subscription in the session cookie then they will always be the same subscription.

Is there a way to distinct the two browsers? (Keep in mind this is not a one page website so I do need to have some way of storing the subscription id so I can show the right data for that specific instance)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'll be able to do it with the basic aspxauth cookie, since it is issued per user, i.e. per log in.  The same with the session cookie, which is shared between the browser instances. Since you support multiple "subscriptions" per user, you'd have to track them manually in each page post.